# Understanding how to use jQuery plugin RhinoSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am attempting to use `RhinoSlider` from http://rhinoslider.com/ but the documentation is very poor at telling you how to use it. It shows you how to *call* it, but not how to build your content for it.

In the demo in the download it uses this..

```
    <div id="page">
        <ul id="slider">
            <li><img src="img/slider/01.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="img/slider/02.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="img/slider/03.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="img/slider/04.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="img/slider/05.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

That doesn't tell me much, do I have to use a similar format? Is the `page` ID anything special? Do I have to use a list?

My code is as below..

```
<div id="slide1" class="slide">
    // Lots of content
</div>
<!-- Slide 1 Ends -->
<div id="slide2" class="slide">
    // Lots of content
</div>
<!-- Slide 2 Ends -->
```

Each slide (slide 1, 2 etc) has a background image which serves as the main image; then the content inside it is div's with text and or other images.

How do I get it to work with my content?

Comment: I would stick to <li> tags for defining slides. Page ID is not important. What is important is the ID of the <ul> tag because you will need that ID to initiate the script. If you need text and images inside your slides you might be able to include HTML inside the <li> tags.

Comment: @effectica Thanks. I changed them to `<li>` tags and it's working for the most part; however I had to change the ID's I was using for the `li` tags to secondary classes as it replaces the ID's with it's own. If you post your response as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any markup you want to.
The only limitation there is, you must have a parent (wrapper) element.

So you can use this:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div>slide 1</div>
    <div>slide 2</div>
</div>
```

Or a more semantic version:

```
<ul id="slider">
    <li>slide 1</li>
    <li>slide 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer! You have a great product, just needs a bit more documentation on how to implement it in some areas.